# Will the compiler optimize for boolean assignment?

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

This is what I want to do:

```
if(ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean))
{
    SomeButton.Enabled = true;
    AnotherButton.Enabled = true;
}
else 
{
    SomeButton.Enabled = false;
    AnotherButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

I can switch this to:

```
SomeButton.Enabled = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean));
AnotherButton.Enabled = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean));
```

For a much more succinct code. My question is, does the compiler optimize the assignment such that it will see that the boolean expression is the same and assign its value for the second button, or will it calculate the value each time.

Note: I understand this is a trivial example and that the speedup/slowdown will be minuscule to the point of inconsequentiality, but it will serve to give me a better understanding of compiler optimization.

Edit: Here is the reason why I thought the second option might be optimized:

```
class Program
{
    static bool ABoolean = true, BBoolean = true, CBoolean = false;
    static bool AEnable, BEnable;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            Operation1();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
        sw1.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            Operation2();
        }
        sw1.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Operation1()
    {
        if (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean))
        {
            AEnable = true;
            BEnable = true;
        }
        else
        {
            AEnable = false;
            BEnable = false;
        }
    }

    static void Operation2()
    {
        AEnable = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean));
        BEnable = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean));
    }
}
```

This resulted in an approximate ~8-9 second difference over the 1 billion operations (with the second option running faster). As I added more "Enable" booleans in however the second operation became slower.

Comment: As an aside: A third way would be through variable assignment: `var enabled = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean))`, then use that variable to set the `.Enabled` properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I wouldn't expect the *compiler* to optimize that. It's possible that the *JIT* could optimize that (as it has more information) but I wouldn't expect the C# compiler to.

How could the compiler know whether `SomeButton.Enabled` will have some side-effect which could change the value of `ABoolean`, `BBoolean` or `CBoolean`?

EDIT: Validation of this... let's give the C# compiler the *absolute most* chance:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(true, false, true);
    }

    static void Foo(bool x, bool y, bool z)
    {
        A = x || (y && z);
        B = x || (y && z);
    }

    static bool A { get; set; }
    static bool B { get; set; }
}
```

Compile with:

```
csc /o+ /debug- Test.cs
```

Code for `Foo` via ILDASM:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Foo(bool x,
                                           bool y,
                                           bool z) cil managed
{
  // Code size       37 (0x25)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  brtrue.s   IL_000c
  IL_0003:  ldarg.1
  IL_0004:  brfalse.s  IL_0009
  IL_0006:  ldarg.2
  IL_0007:  br.s       IL_000d
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000a:  br.s       IL_000d
  IL_000c:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000d:  call       void Test::set_A(bool)
  IL_0012:  ldarg.0
  IL_0013:  brtrue.s   IL_001e
  IL_0015:  ldarg.1
  IL_0016:  brfalse.s  IL_001b
  IL_0018:  ldarg.2
  IL_0019:  br.s       IL_001f
  IL_001b:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001c:  br.s       IL_001f
  IL_001e:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_001f:  call       void Test::set_B(bool)
  IL_0024:  ret
} // end of method Test::Foo
```

As you can see, the expression really is evaluated in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was getting confused because I actually timed the two options and was getting significantly faster results with the second option. I am assuming this is due to the overhead of the if/else clause. There should therefore be a point of no return in number of boolean operations in the second case that results in slower time right?

Comment: @NominSim: I wouldn't expect *significantly* faster results with either version. I'm suspicious of your diagnostics :) But really, is this likely to be even slightly significant overall for you?

Comment: Well over a billion operations the difference was ~8 seconds (~19 vs ~11)...I suppose significant is subjective, and when I added 5 more boolean assignments the second option became slower. Definitely not even slightly significant, I was just explaining how I originally came to the conclusion that it might be optimizing the second version.

Comment: @NominSim: That certainly sounds interesting - but it's really easy to break tests for micro-optimizations; in particular you could easily find that one version was inlined and another not, but wouldn't have an impact in a larger method.

Comment: I edited in my OP the code for my tests, I am not sure if Stopwatch is the best way to time this sort of thing...do you mind glancing at it and seeing if it seems feasible?

Comment: @NominSim - You should get rid of the method call inside the loop.  Function call overhead is more substantial than the operation itself.  Secondly, the JIT compiler can sometimes interfere with doing timings like this.  You might want to run through each operation a few million times before you start timing as a way to warm up the JIT, so to speak.  I ran a similar test a few minutes ago and doing this made a  difference of around 20%.

Comment: @SteveWortham The method calls are an attempt to forestall any loop unrolling optimization that are wont to occur without it. (AFAIK the overhead should be the same with each loop and therefore inconsequential to the results).

Comment: @NominSim - OK, but I still think you're going to experience a bias towards the second test with your current code.  Flipping the order of the tests could prove my point.

Comment: @SteveWortham I flipped the tests as you suggested and got nearly identical results (+/- milliseconds). As Jon pointed out the optimization isn't there for the second test, but I think given the triviality of the operation, and the added overhead of the if/then loop results in the second being faster. The first op still does: eval the expression, perform the if/else branch, assign to bools(x2), whereas the first does: eval the expression(x2) and assign to bools(x2). The only difference it seems to me is the if/then branch, creating slightly longer time for small examples.

Comment: @NominSim - It's funny but in my tests, the two techniques have identical performance in x64 code.  But in x86 code, the first method is actually faster.  In a sense, this is the opposite of your results.  Of course, my test doesn't involve a method call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12039/discussion-between-nominsim-and-steve-wortham)

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, does the compiler optimize the assignment such that it will see that the boolean expression is the same and assign its value for the second button, or will it calculate the value each time.

It will calculate the value each time.

What if this was a multi-threaded application. Some other thread might change it.

If they are not constant variables, they can be changed.

To optimise you can do

```
SomeButton.Enabled = AnotherButton.Enabled = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean));
```

In this case it will be calculated once and value assigned first to `AnotherButton` first and `SomeButton` later. Remember its right to left in assignment.

Comment: Right.  Because these are two separate statements involving variables that are not constants.  So the compiler must not assume anything here.  The variables might have changed between these two statements, especially if your application is multi-threaded.

Comment: Now you're just taking details from other people's answers.  It's hilarious.  But I'm not sure what you posted is really an optimization.  Boolean evaluation is *extremely* fast.  And I think referencing the `get` accessor of properties typically has the same overhead as calling an inline method.  So this could easily be slower than the original code.  Albeit, we're talking about nanoseconds, but still.

Comment: @SteveWortham: Yeah i admit i copied it.  But not from somebody's answer but from my brain.

Comment: Actually, the `get` accessor won't be referenced, because the return value of an assignment is the value that was assigned.  So, the boolean expression would be evaluated once, and then returned down the chain.  There are subtle effects that may come up if there are different types in the assignment chain, but that's not at issue here.

Comment: @SteveCzetty: Thanks. One Steve for rescue against another Steve.

Comment: @SteveCzetty - I thought that the `get` accessor for `AnotherButton.Enabled` would be accessed in this case.  I ran a test just now and sure enough doing it this way is more than twice as slow as the original code.

Comment: @SteveCzetty - I ran another test and you are right that the `get` accessor is never called.  But I'm still not sure why it's so much slower.

Comment: @SteveWortham I didn't run any tests, but I don't know why it would be so much slower, either.  Doesn't seem like it would be an issue, but maybe there's some boxing going on or something.

Answer (score 2):

No, the complier will not optimize it in my experience, however, you can do:

```
SomeButton.Enabled = AnotherButton.Enabled = (ABoolean || (BBoolean && CBoolean));
```